# Needed solution to resolve intermittent SocketTimeoutException while inserting data into HBase through Apache Storm Bolt

Tags: hbase, apache-storm

Requesting some help / pointers into a issue I am facing.

We have a solution wherein we are reading Web Server log files from Windows through Apache Kafka and then processing it through Storm which is then to be stored in HBase. We have been able to complete the first 2 parts – reading the files through Kafka and processing it through Storm. But we are facing issues while storing the processed data into HBase.

To store into HBase, we have written a Storm Bolt which reads the data, processes it (simple processing to split the line as per the delimiter) and then sends it into HBase. In the bolt, we are creating the HBase connection using the ConnectionFactory Java API and we are able to see the same getting established through the logs.

Once the spout and the previous bolt passes data, we are seeing an inconsistent behavior in the HBase bolt. At times, it goes ahead and inserts the data into HBase (we were able to verify the same through the bolt log and also through hbase shell) but at other times, it throws a SocketTimeoutException (included below). The exception goes away when we restart HBase (sometimes one restart works while other times we have had to restart 2-3 times).

On executing the code, the Bolt is triggered but no rows get inserted. On the Storm UI, we see that the log shows a SocketTimeoutException. This goes away after we restart HBase couple of times and then the rows get inserted. This process of restarting HBase has to be done each time else we end up with the SocketTimeoutException. During this time, we see that the spout and previous bolt are working fine (changing emit and transferred numbers in the Storm UI in Ambari).

We are seeing 2 scenarios:

1. The HBase bolt does no reaqing as per the bolt log. This is even though the previous bolt and spout show data being emitted. This goes away once HBase cluster is restarted.
2. The HBase related bolt shows data being read through the Storm UI and the bolt log but the same is not seen inserted into HBASE Table (as verified through HBase SHell).

Request for some pointers on how best we can resolve this? We have tried executing the run after clearing the Storm Local Directory and restarting the full cluster as well.

Environment Details:
Apache Kafka - 0.9.0
Apache Storm - 0.10.0

Exception Details

```
2017-11-24 07:19:36.562 k.c.SimpleConsumer [INFO] Reconnect due to error:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
     at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:211) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
     at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
     at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
     at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:81) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely(BlockingChannel.scala:140) ~[kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:131) ~[kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:102) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:99) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:148) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:148) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:148) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:147) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:147) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:147) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:146) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:54) [kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:?]
     at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.fetchMessages(KafkaUtils.java:165) [storm-kafka-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
     at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.fill(PartitionManager.java:170) [storm-kafka-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
     at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.next(PartitionManager.java:132) [storm-kafka-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
     at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:144) [storm-kafka-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
     at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__6191$fn__6206$fn__6235.invoke(executor.clj:601) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
     at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:479) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
     at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
```